# Can an Azure Function access internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda

... or, rather, what's involved in arranging that access?

I'd like to try out AWS Lambda and Azure Functions, and have in mind a toy application which would on schedule call a Web API - or scrape a web page - grab some data, and save it to file. I worry that the "internet access" part might not be straightforward; initial googling suggested that for AWS Lambda, I would need to obtain some "NAT" (?), at $30 pm, and for Azure Functions, I did not find anything. Can anyone advise?

Comment: You don't need to do anything specific to get outbound internet access. You'll only pay for the time your function runs. Where you save the scraped data to is something to consider. If this is just a test then save it to the local file system of the function but be aware that it may not be persistent. If you need to persist it, then write it to object storage (like S3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both AWS Lambda and Azure Functions can access internet by default.

Note: If you do advance configurations, for example putting an AWS Lambda function inside a VPC, that is where you need to use a NAT Gateway (Paying additionally) to access the internet.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @4c74356b41 answer:

Your search might not have shown what you have searched for.

AWS Lambda functions don't have internet access only when they are inside VPC.

By default, Lambdas aren't created in any VPC so they have Internet access.

What you have found on Google is only true for AWS Lambda functions inside A VPC.

Comment: sorry, no idea about aws

Answer (score 1):

Azure function got external\outbound internet access. I'm not even sure how you would block it. So yes. its got that.